# Ruby require_relative executing script?

Tags: ruby, windows, eclipse, require, relative-path

I'm working on a game server in ruby, and during testing I'm having trouble testing components individually. I wasn't getting output from my launcher, just the server, so I commented out the initialisation of the server- yet eclipse still showed output from the server!

I then went to the command line, assuming eclipse was looking at the wrong file (git has messed it around before, but as you can see, the stack trace shows that `Server.rb` is being executed in its entirety from line 5: `require_relative 'Server'`:

[image: Sublime/cmd screenshot]

This is the text content of the file:

```
class Launcher


  puts "File saved at #{File.mtime($0)}"


  require_relative 'Server'
  require_relative 'Game'

  #STDOUT.sync = true

  puts "Launcher started"
  #server = Server.new
  print "server made"
  game = Game.new
  #serverThread = Thread.new{server.start()}
  gameThread = Thread.new{game.start()}

  while (running)
    print "Stop? "
    input = gets.chomp
    if (input.equals?("yes"))
      running = false
    end
  end

  server.stop
  game.stop
  gameThread.join
  serverThread.join

end
```

and the terminal output:

```
C:\Users\gossfunkel\git\citadelserver\RubyCitadelServer>ruby Launcher.rb
File saved at 2013-06-22 18:16:44 +0100
Server starting up at 2013-06-22 18:16:47 +0100...
C:/Users/gossfunkel/git/citadelserver/RubyCitadelServer/Server.rb:20:in `recvfro
m': Interrupt
        from C:/Users/gossfunkel/git/citadelserver/RubyCitadelServer/Server.rb:2
0:in `run'
        from C:/Users/gossfunkel/git/citadelserver/RubyCitadelServer/Server.rb:1
5:in `start'
        from C:/Users/gossfunkel/git/citadelserver/RubyCitadelServer/Server.rb:3
0:in `<class:Server>'
        from C:/Users/gossfunkel/git/citadelserver/RubyCitadelServer/Server.rb:1
:in `<top (required)>'
        from Launcher.rb:5:in `require_relative'
        from Launcher.rb:5:in `<class:Launcher>'
        from Launcher.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

How do I require a file without this happening, and should it be?

Comment: Please post text, not screenshots. The image is unreadable without somne magnification and cannot be copy-pasted.

Comment: Sorry, had assumed image would be larger. I can't seem to copy-paste from cmd but I've put the Launcher code in.

Comment: Ah you're on Windows. For future reference, to copy from a `cmd` window, right-click anywhere on it; choose `Mark` from the context menu; drag a rectangle with your mouse pointer; press `return` on the keyboard. Now it's on your clipboard. You may need to paste it into an editor and tidy it up.

Comment: @gossfunkel See http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/copy-to-the-clipboard-from-the-windows-command-prompt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell without seeing the classes, but I would guess that either

- `game.start` is doing more than you thought, and is starting the server for itself
- You are, as your subject line suggests, running a different file from the one you are editing (or not saving the file once it is changed). Check by putting an obvious `puts` at the top of the program. Something like

  ```
  puts "File saved at #{File.mtime($0)}"
  ```

  should do the trick
- After discussion, it seems there's a third option. The code in `Server.pm` creates and runs a server as well as defining the class. You need to remove the `require` as well as the lines that use the `Server` class.

Comment: I added the line and it worked absolutely fine- but the `puts "Launcher started"` line still doesn't run. What's more, I've just spotted that the stack trace states that Server.rb is being run from line 5: `require_relative 'Server'`!

Comment: Yes, I can believe that. `require` *executes* any executable statements in the file you're requiring. Remove the `require` as well as the calls and you should be OK.

Comment: Oh! So how do I use classes from other files _without_ executing?

Comment: You write your classes in files with nothing else in them. Then `require` and call them from other files.

Comment: I've just realised how **massively** foolish I've been. Thanks for helping me spot my error!

Comment: By the way, your class `Server` will conventionally be in a file called `server.rb`. Note the lack of capitals. So `Net::HTTP` is in a file `net/http.rb`.

Comment: No worries. Everybody has to learn. Mistakes are the quickest way.